# Notation for $\log \log \cdots \log n$?

Tags: notation

Is there some accepted, more concise notation for expressions like $\log \log \log n$?
I just noticed [an arXiv posting](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029) that quotes the bound
$$
\frac{\log X \log \log X \log \log \log \log X}
{ \log \log \log X}
$$
and I wonder if there is room for some notational improvement in this domain.
Clearly $\log^k n$ is not an option, as that seems entrenched in the literature
to mean $(\log n)^k$.

If there is no accepted, more concise notation, perhaps the community could invent
a notation.

Comment: Is this research level?

Comment: @Andreas, where, other than in research papers on analytic number theory, is one likely to come across $\log\log\log\log x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You are right, with four logs it must be research.

Comment: Iterated logarithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm.

Comment: ... meaning, four logs is for lumberjacks, real research has infinitely many.

Comment: Semantic satiation has set in; after reading this, "log" no longer registers as a word.

Comment: @Mirko, I think the dynamical system given by the logarithm is not very interesting. I doubt there is a paper in the dynamical systems literature where anyone has used a 4-times iterated logarithm.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question has been placed on hold. If [asking for the notation for the all-ones vector](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9898/notation-for-the-all-ones-vector) is a valid question for MO, I don't see why this isn't.

Comment: @DavidZhang That was 5 1/2 years ago. The standards and expectations evolve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Analytic Number Theorists have been using $\log_nx$ for the $n$-times iterated (natural) logarithm of $x$ for some time. See, e.g., the first page of [this paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/primegaps.pdf) by Ford, Green, Konyagin, and Tao. Alternatively, Claudia Spiro used $L_4x$ for $\log\log\log\log x$ in [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa68/aa6842.pdf).

Comment: Ha! This is pretty much the same paper Joseph cites in the question --- just go past the abstract, and look at page 2!

Comment: Well -- ${\rm log}_n x$ could be mistaken for the logarithm for base $n$ of $x$.

Comment: @Stefan, yes --- so whenever it's used for the iterated logarithm, the author(s) carefully explain just what they mean by it (as in the Ford et al. paper).

Comment: Excuse the rant, but just to go out of the way of the imbeciles who write $\log^nx$ to save two keystrokes (counting the space that TeX requires) from the completely unambiguous $(\ln x)^n$, ANT people go abuse a notation that half of humanity uses for something quite different! At the very least they could have come up with something like $\log_{(n)}x$ or $\log^{(n)}x$ (yes, that is $4$ more keystrokes, unless you define a macro). When will we mathematicians grow up?

Comment: @Marc, I think the part of humanity that has a use for logarithms-to-the-base-4 is disjoint from the part of humanity that has a use for $\log\log\log\log x$, so using $\log_4x$ for the latter isn't likely to even come to the attention of anyone who would have expected the former. And, as I mentioned, the convention is to explain the notation immediately upon first using it, so no one will be confused for long.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The same issue arises with trigonometric functions. I wish people wrote $(\sin x)^2$ instead of $\sin^2 x$, since the latter makes $\sin^{-1}$ ambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

I have seen the notation $F^{\circ2}(x)$ and $F^{\circ n}(x)$ in a [Dynamical Systems book by Shlomo Sternberg](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/) (see e.g. section 2.2.2 Period doubling, there). Clearly $\circ$ indicates that we are talking about composition of functions and distinguishes it from $F^2(x)$ and $F^n(x)$ if you interpret the latter as $(F(x))^2$ and $(F(x))^n$. So one might perhaps use $\log^{\circ4}n$ and $\log^{\circ k}n$. I would personally prefer this, since $\log_4n$ could be confused with $\log$ with base $4$, though I am sure people in analytic number theory know what they mean with their choice of notation.

Comment: As I have mentioned (twice!), people in analytic number theory *explain* what they mean with their choice of notation.

Comment: yes @GerryMyerson but everybody writes, nobody reads ... I did eventually read it (before you reminded me but after I posted my answer). Yet, I would argue that good notation needs little or no explanation.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about generally accepted, but $\log^{(n)}X$ seems pretty concise. It conforms to the usual notation for functional iterations and there is no room for confusion with either taking powers or using different bases, e.g. $(\log_2^{(n)}X)^k$.

Comment: There is room for confusion for the $n$th derivative of the $\log$ function, though.

Comment: True. However, if it comes to the $n$th derivative of $\log$, the context is usually such that it's more preferable to use differential operator notation instead, or the simple explicit expression for it.

Comment: The slightly different notation $\log^{[n]}{X}$, which avoids clearly the conflict with derivatives, was my immediate reaction to the title of this question.

Answer (score 5):

I find $(\text{log}^k)(n)$ quite clear, with little or no potential for misunderstanding.

Comment: To carefully specify composition, we can use $\log^{\circ k} n$