# Why is the matrix of all 1's called "J"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, terminology

I've seen J referenced recently in some discussion about algebraic combinatorics, and it took me a while to figure out it was the matrix of all ones. It came up without definition, and I spent too long trying to google "what is a J matrix".

I found this, but I can find no reference to the convention of using J to represent the matrix. Maybe it's arbitrary?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones

Comment: One guess is that the identity matrix already has a well-established claim on the more natural-seeming "I", so "J" is the next alternative.

Comment: Probably something to do with choices made by people creating computer algebra systems?

Comment: I see $E$ in some 1950s sources.

Comment: It's (almost) idempotent, like in split complex numbers?

Comment: I certainly saw $J$ in papers  from mid-1980-ies,

Comment: At least it is not an 'O' for "all Ones".

Comment: Perhaps it's from Jednostka, the Polish word for unit.

Comment: See the related question (which has a bunch of answers, then ended up being closed)  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9898/notation-for-the-all-ones-vector

Comment: Hoffman and Singleton use $J$ in their paper on Moore graphs from the 60s. It would be nice to know what is the oldest appearance of this notation.

Comment: Somewhat related question on Mathematics Stack Exchange: [How do you write / represent the 'all ones matrix'?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307353)

Answer (score 0):

You have a matrix only filled with 1s, so it would be neat to have a notation resembling this. You could use

- $1$, $\mathbf 1$ or $\mathbb 1$ but these are usually a danger for confusion with the scalar and the latter one is often used to represent the all-1s-vector already.
- a letter similar to 1, e.g. $I$, $\mathbf I$ or $\mathbb I$, but these are usually used for the identity matrix already.

So you go with the next best letter that resembles a "1" $-$ namely $J$. However, I also have seen $E$. I would say that if you have some experience in the topic, you can spot this from the context. But a well-written text would introduce this notation nevertheless.

Comment: Unfortunately $E$ is also commonly used for a matrix with only one non-zero entry (often subscripted, like $E_{i j}$).

Comment: If we are going to be unfortunate, then J is also used in almost-complex geometry/analysis to stand for a completely different matrix that squares to -1 (called the "symplectic matrix" or something like that).